# Is it possible to unzip a compressed file with multiple threads?

Tags: bash, unzip

I unzip using this :

```
unzip -q "file.zip" -d path
```

How can I unzip faster with utilizing multiple cores and threads?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain a bit, what do you mean by multi-core here?

Comment: Why is multicore an issue here ? Do you mean you have big zip files and want to use multi threading to speed up the process ?

Comment: Interesting read: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-leverage-multiple-cores-while-unzipping-a-zip-file-Linux

Comment: I would like to be able to tell unzip to use 4 CPUs, for example is it possible?

Comment: Following the argumentation in the article I've linked, even if it would be possible, you won't gain so much extra speed.

Comment: hek2mgl It does not solve my problem, I would like to use the same tool

Comment: you can use **pigz** https://zlib.net/pigz/ a multithread implementation of gzip both when compressing and decompressing. Since gzip works on a single file when compressing a directory (eventually with subdirectories) you have to first make a `tar` archive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short: No, unzipping with multiple cores is not available.

The decompression normally has lower CPU-intensity than the compression (where multiple cores are often involved).

You wouldn't have much of an advantage anyway as the read/write-operations are more of the bottlenecks during decompression.

Comment: Ok thanks for your explain :)

Comment: NVMe SSDs are super fast, but unzipping a 6gb file still takes ages. Pretty sure the CPU is the bottleneck. What gives?

Comment: Using https://github.com/lukehutch/quickunzip unzipping Xcode10.2.zip takes 2m26s, using Archive Utility on Mac - 3m55s

Comment: It is the CPU bottlenecking it, 1 core will always be maxed out newer NVMe based drives, indicating the bottleneck

Comment: try ripunzip: https://medium.com/@adetaylor/does-parallel-unzipping-work-cdaf89124c88

(I built static version for local testing https://github.com/hemnstill/StandaloneTools/releases/tag/ripunzip-0.4.0)

its x2 - x4 times faster then unzip

Comment: As long as your NVMe drive is fast enough, decompressing large zip files can benefit from multiple CPU cores. Lots of cores, in fact. See the benchmarks at https://youtu.be/c2tzTMN6-qU?t=636. There's plenty of scaling with core count on that chart. Threadripper generally has lower clock rates than its normal desktop brethren, but beats them easily.

Answer (score 0):

thy [pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) which takes advantage of the multi cores and unzips in multiple threads

Comment: as per [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pigz), pigz doesn't use multi threading for decompression

Comment: Still better than unzip. `pigz uses a single thread (the main thread) for decompression, but will create three other threads for reading, writing, and check calculation, which can speed up decompression under some circumstances.`